# Export Pandas dataframe to custom CSV format with JSON rows

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

In my pandas program I am reading a csv and converting some columns as json

For ex: my csv is like this:

```
id_4 col1  col2 .....................................col100
1     43    56  .....................................67
2     46    67   ....................................78
```

What I want to achieve is:

id_4 json

```
1  {"col1":43,"col2":56,.....................,"col100":67}
2  {"col1":46,"col2":67,.....................,"col100":78}
```

The code what I have tried is as follows:

```
    df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
    def func(df):         
        d = [
        dict([
        (colname, row[i])        
        for i,colname in enumerate(df[['col1','col2',............,'col100']])

        for row in zip(df['col1'].astype(str),df['col2'].astype(str),...............,df['col100'].astype(str))]

        format_data = json.dumps(d)
        format_data = format_data[1:len(format_data)-1]
        json_data = '{"key":'+format_data+'}' 
        result.append(pd.Series([df['id_4'].unique()[0],json_data],index = headers))                                        
        return df   

    df.groupby('id_4').apply(func)

b = open('output.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(b)
writer.writerow(headers)
writer.writerows(result[1:len(result)])
```

The CSV contains some 100 000 data, memory is (15 MB). when I execute this, after a long time the process is killed automatically. I think its a memory issue.

As I am newbie to this python and pandas, Is there any way to optimize the above code to work properly or increasing the memory is the only way.

I am using 5GB RAM Linux System.

EDIT:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Vill_inter.csv')
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for id_4, row in itertools.izip(df.index.values, df.to_dict(orient='records')):
        writer.writerow((id_4, json.dumps(row))
```

Comment: `['col1','col2',............,'col100']` is equivalent to `['col'+str(n) for n in range(1, 101)]`

Comment: no error, just letting you know an alternative way to write it to express the same thing more concisely in real python without any "shorthand" notation such as `..........`. It can also help clean up your code.

Comment: As far as errors go, your code sample has mismatched parens and braces.

Comment: @Francis Usher i just pasted a snippet of code. i didn't noticed parens and braces.

Comment: @Francis Usher  is any solution is there for this?? or any alternate way to achieve the result??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas dataframe can be directly serializable in JSON with `to_json` method.

Your output format is not very clear but have a look at this:

```
# Generate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 100), columns=['col' + str(n) for n in xrange(1, 101)])
# Create id_4 column
df.index += 1
df.index.name = 'id_4'
# Reindex df to have the column id_4 in the output, remove if you only columns1 to X
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)

# Dump data to disk, or buffer
path = 'out.json'
df.to_json(path, orient='records')
```

It is gonna be much faster than your loops and will probably solve your error.

EDIT:

Apparently the output should be a custom fileformat. In this case you can output the dataframe using `to_dict(orient='records)`. The output will be a list where each element represents a row as a dictionary. You can serialize the dictionary using the `dumps` function of the `json` module (built-in).

Something like this:

```
import json
import itertools

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for id, row in itertools.izip(df.index.values, df.to_dict(orient='records')):
        writer.writerow((id, json.dumps(row)))
```

Comment: also its possible to add key to that json

Comment: It depends if you indexed your dataframe with the column `id_4` or not. If you skip the line `df.reset_index(..)`, it works.

Comment: Please do not change your requirements and try to understand the code. or ask another question. My answer should be accepted ..